# is it ok magento have shell_exec() - magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, security

My extension needs to run some docker commands from the ajax controller so I use PHP [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function.

is it ok Magento have shell_exec()?

I'm looking the advice related to Magento security, whether it creates any security vulnerability or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is more related to PHP programming than Magento itself.

It is never a good idea to use `shell_exec` unless it is the only option you have. In Magento is more than a bad idea because it is **exposed to world wide**.

Why don't you create a webservice to trigger the commands you need? You could create a small server using NodeJS, Pyhon or whatever you like. Magento could call this webservice triggering the command.

This will decouple Magento and the `shell_exec` command. It is much more safe than putting it inside Magento.